# Why doesn't the console show the entire output?

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to generate prime numbers by making each thread compute whether a number is prime on not.
Since the device printf() has limited buffer, is there any way to redirect the output to the host and printing it without any overwrites?Thanks

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


__device__ unsigned long long counter = 2;
__global__ void prime()
{
    unsigned long long num = atomicAdd(&counter, 1);
    long k = 0;
    for (long i = 2; i <= sqrt((double)num) && k!=1; i++){
        if (num % i == 0){
            k = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (k != 1)
        printf("%ld ", num);
}

int main()
{
    int block=2,threads=1000;
    prime <<<block,threads>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to bypass this limitation?

Comment: Yes, and it is discussed in the duplicate answer